# Limit android process CPU usage

Tags: android, linux, process

My app is using OpenGl on the native side. But the CPU is only 400mHz. Sometimes when app need to draw many details, CPU consumption is 100%. Is it possible to limit CPU usage of whole application process? (e.g. my app couldn't use more than 40% of CPU)

Thanks.

Comment: `kill -9 <pid>` will limit the CPU usage very effectively.

Comment: Your app is slow, and so you want to make it *slower*?!

Comment: My app should work with another important app. But important app works slow because my app picks up all the CPU time.

Comment: @p37td8: If you limit its CPU usage, it'll just make the important app work slow for longer. You *want* your app to get all the CPU usage that's left over after the important app so it can get its work done without competing. You're asking the wrong question. The right question is: "How can I reduce my application's priority so it doesn't adversely affect more important applications?"